# Distributing a data access solution across multiple solutions

Tags: .net, architecture, git, deployment, builds

I have 3 solutions, one of them is a dataccess solution with all the repositories etc. At the moment when a change is made to it, the others have to go get the latest nuget version locally, we have a nuget server on the LAN. Its a pain to debug though.

Would a git submodule work here to enable debugging and not worry about updating nuget packages?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something to handle your dependency management. In that case, I'd recommend looking into Maven. You can integrate Maven into your builds so that new revisions of library code are automatically downloaded and incorporated (using SNAPSHOTS).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a data access solution? You act as if that's a best practice.

Data Access is a *layer*, not its own initiative.

You should refactor your code so that the data access projects are used by the other solutions. Data access shouldn't be implemented as its own solution.

Comment: Data Access solution exists as its own thing as I have 2 other solutions consuming it. I don't really want the 2 solutions consuming it in the same repository